# Filter an array by key and value by accessing an array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, arraylist, filter

### How to filter array from key and value that is inside an array?

I need to filter the items of an array by the key and value from within an array, this key will always contain boolean values.

I know there are some ways to do this, but I would like a more recommended way to do this, because when it comes to too many records this can affect filter performance.

```
[
      {name: 'PERSON1', 
      info_add: {name: 'obs', active: true, faithful: false}.........},

      {name: 'PERSON2', 
      info_add: {name: 'obs', active: true, faithful: true}.........},

      {name: 'PERSON3', 
      info_add: {name: 'obs', active: false, faithful: true}.........},
]
```

I need to fit inside `info_add` by the `active` key or by the `faithful` key if the value is false or true.

> active = true => PERSON1 object, PERSON2 object
>
> active = false => PERSON3 object
>
> faithful = true => PERSON2 object, PERSON3 object
>
> faithful = false => PERSON1 object

As my array is very large and I have other arrays inside, I would like to know how best to filter objects from `active` and `faithful`.

Currently I'm only filtering through string values ​​with the method below, but I'd like to create another method to improve filter performance.

```
public static filterArrayByString(mainArr, searchText)
{
    if ( searchText === '' )
    {
        return mainArr;
    }

    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    return mainArr.filter(itemObj => {
        console.log(itemObj);
        return this.searchInObj(itemObj, searchText);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const _ = require('lodash');

var arr = [
{
    name: 'PERSON1',
    info_add: {name: 'obs', active: true, faithful: false}
},
{
    name: 'PERSON2',
    info_add: {name: 'obs', active: true, faithful: true}
},

{
    name: 'PERSON3',
    info_add: {name: 'obs', active: false, faithful: true}
}];

var activeFiltered = _.filter(arr, function(person){
    return person.info_add.active;
});

var faithfulFiltered = _.filter(arr, function(person){
    return person.info_add.faithful;
});

console.log(activeFiltered);
console.log(faithfulFiltered);
```

You can use lodash to apply filters easily on arrays using the filter function.
The first line is just the NodeJS way of using lodash, rest is the same.

In callback function to the filter function each item in the array can be individually accessed for conditions to decide if the item should be in the filtered array or not.
return true means item will be included, return false means item will not be included.

Comment: See [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the native equivalent.